# Are the contents of .git/rebase-apply documented?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Upon a conflict during `rebase`, I realized that there are many files under `.git/rebase-apply` that could be potentially useful for the user. Some appear to have Boolean contents (like `t` and `f`), and some others are Boolean by mere presence (like `rebasing`).

The semantics of some are clear from the file name itself, like `orig-head`.
But I wonder if the contents of the directory are (i.e. what they are, what they mean, what all are expected at what event etc.) documented somewhere.

Answer (score -2):

When rebase, if you get conflic, please fix your conflic.

Then, excute command:

- git add
- git rebase --continue

You will escape rebasing!